Astro with Tailwind and Flowbite does not work when deploy
I created a new Astro project with tailwind and I'm using Flowbite as a component library.
On localhost, everything works perfectly but when I try to deploy to Vercel with mode 'server' or 'hybrid', I have two 404 errors in the browser console. One for the min.js file from Flowbite and other for a custom script that I use to handle the user preferred color scheme.
Package.json
    {
     "name": "astro-portfolio",
     "type": "module",
     "version": "0.0.1",
    "scripts": {
     "dev": "astro dev",
     "start": "astro dev",
     "build": "astro check && astro build",
     "preview": "astro preview",
     "astro": "astro"
    },
    "dependencies": {
     "@astrojs/check": "^0.7.0",
     "@astrojs/tailwind": "^5.1.0",
     "@astrojs/vercel": "^7.6.0",
     "@emailjs/browser": "^4.3.3",
     "@fontsource-variable/raleway": "^5.0.18",
     "@fontsource/finger-paint": "^5.0.18",
     "astro": "^4.8.6",
     "tailwind-merge": "^2.3.0",
     "tailwind-scrollbar": "^3.1.0",
     "tailwindcss": "^3.4.3",
     "typescript": "^5.4.5"
    },
     "devDependencies": {
      "flowbite": "^2.3.0",
      "sass": "^1.71.1"
     }
    }

This is my astro.config.mjs:
    export default defineConfig({
     integrations: [tailwind()],
     compressHTML: true,
     output: "hybrid",
     adapter: vercel()
    });

And on my Layout.astro, inside head tag:
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="canonical" href="http://localhost:4321/" />
    <meta name="generator" content={Astro.generator} />
    <meta name="keywords" content={metadata.keywords.join(", ")} />
    <meta name="description" content={metadata.description} />
    <meta name="author" content="Javier Moreno" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta property="og:title" content={metadata.title} />
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="" />
    <meta property="og:description" content={metadata.description} />
    <title>{title}</title>
    <script src="node_modules/flowbite/dist/flowbite.min.js"></script>
    <script src="src/assets/js/themes"></script>
</head>

The errors on app deployed:


Are you running node on the vercel endpoint? The flowbite.min.js actually resides in node_module folder that's what is missing (404).

I setup the vercel adapter for the project. Finally i delete the flowbite import and do the function with vanilla js. Im confused how that works but that for comment.
